# How to change default Oracle 11g to 19c in cli Windows 10?

Tags: database, oracle, command-line-interface

How to change default Oracle 11g to 19c in cli Windows 10?

I have 2 Oracle db releases on my Windows 10: 11g & 19c.
When I enter cmd line (or any shell), type sqlplus I am by defalut connected to 11g release.

I would like to change default db in cmd to 19c. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

We will follow the PATH variable in the absence of anything else, eg

```
c:\>set PATH=C:\oracle\product\19\bin;%PATH%

c:\>sqlplus /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Feb 16 18:32:44 2021
Version 19.8.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2020, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

c:\>set PATH=C:\oracle\product\18\bin;%PATH%

c:\>sqlplus /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Feb 16 18:33:08 2021
Version 18.6.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
```

Then set your ORACLE_SID or connect via a service as already mentioned

Answer (score 0):

**Usually** we use TNSNAMES.ORA file which contains "aliases" to databases we access. Then, while connecting to a desired database, we specify its alias:

```
sqlplus scott/tiger@ora11g
```

or

```
sqlplus mike/lion@ora19c
```

Although you may have access to only 2 databases, my TNSNAMES.ORA contains entries for 55 of them. What I'm trying to say is that you may consider "one" database "default", but as the time goes by, that "default" will either change or will be mostly useless as you'll connect to different databases on a daily bases. Therefore, check your TNSNAMES.ORA, specify its alias along with username/password and ... that's it.